# How to calculate the closest co-ordinates to a given point from a client on server side

Tags: java, android, algorithm, google-maps, spatial

I have a user current location and a radius which I send to server.
I want server to return only locations inside a given radius.
(I am not sure how many locations I will have in server's DB)

Application written in Java for android platform and server written in Java.

**Edited:** 
[Spatial MySQL DB](http://www.arubin.org/files/geo_search.pdf)
,Found this very helpful after seeing the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [Spatial database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database), they can handle such requests.